# How to make Rails use the getter method of a property when saving the activerecord on DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an activerecord like this

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: cars
#
#  id                  :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
#  year                :integer
#  type                :string(255)
#
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  def type
    return self[:type] if self[:type].present?
    year > 2010 ? 'new' : 'old'
  end
end
```

When I run `Car.create(year: 2019)` it is saving the **type** as **nil** instead use the getter value.

Is it possible to use the getter value on saving in database?

- I would like to avoid to put the logic on **year** setter if it is possible
- As the **year** value can be set after **Car** the **after_create** event don't works for me

Comment: Also you may want to avoid using “type” as column name, it’s a keyword used by STI.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `type` when setting the `year`. For that, override the default setter for `year`:

```rb
def year=(value)
  super
  self.type = value > 2010 ? 'new' : 'old'
end
```

`Car.create(year: 2019)` will call each property's setter, in this case `#year=`, which will set the `type`.

Comment: Got it... I would like to avoid put the code on the year setter, but it seems there is no other way, isn't?

Comment: Yes, there is. Use a `before_save` and check if year was changed: `<your logic> if year_changed?`[API](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html)

Comment: @AlanAlvesdeOliveira why do you want to avoid it? This is the most consistent one, i.e. whenever year changes, this logic kicks in.

Answer (score 0):

Your `after_create` is not working because you're not saving it afterwards.

you can use `:before_create`

```
def set_type
  if year
    self.type = year > 2010 ? 'new' : 'old'
  end
end
```